# How can i install Blender 2.8 in ubuntu 18.4 with only console?

Tags: python, rendering, linux

today i use

`apt-get install blender`

in my Linux server (which has no screen or any display service but pure SSH remote connection)

,but the installed blender version is not 2.8 ,it is old version

and i tried

`apt-get install blender=2.8`

But end with `not found 2.8`

i google for a while but find nothing about install  blender 2.8 in Linux without screen device ,mainly of them are referred to install with display device like use snap software (a software shop mall in Linux)

is there any solution to apply?
Thanks if you have any ideas!!!

Comment: Take it this relates to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170821/why-fail-when-i-render-blender-in-linux-vps-machine).  2.82a is available to install via snap, see `snap info blender`  Consult stackoverflow or ask ubuntu re installing snap and installing with snap.

Comment: sorry ,snap install will show `error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image
       using "squashfs": mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-291580849: mount
       failed: Operation not permitted.`

Comment: See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs-operation-not-permitted/13829  or simply copy a blackbox zip install of blender, or build blender on server.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify yamalai's `wget` answer, which currently doesn't work for me due to a broken link, you can find a list of all the releases of Blender at https://download.blender.org/release/. Suppose you want to use version 2.82a. Simply go to the appropriate release, right-click the desired file, and copy the link address as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

On an Ubuntu 18.04 machine, type `wget` and paste the link:

```
$ wget https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.82/blender-2.82a-linux64.tar.xz
--2020-05-29 20:47:53--  https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.82/blender-2.82a-linux64.tar.xz
Resolving download.blender.org (download.blender.org)... 82.94.213.221
Connecting to download.blender.org (download.blender.org)|82.94.213.221|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 134381616 (128M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘blender-2.82a-linux64.tar.xz’
blender-2.82a-linux64.tar.xz                      100%[===========================================================================================================>] 128.16M  3.98MB/s    in 44s     
2020-05-29 20:48:37 (2.91 MB/s) - ‘blender-2.82a-linux64.tar.xz’ saved [134381616/134381616]
```

This should give you a `*.tar.xz` file, which for me was 129M. Type

```
tar xvf blender-2.82a-linux64.tar.xz
```

The `v` is optional and is just for verbosity. To check afterwards that the installation worked, you can `cd` into the resulting Blender directory and type `./blender --version`.

Answer (score 1):

Installing from repositories is not recommended, they are hardly ever up-to-date.

Blender doesn't need to be "installed".

From a command line use **`wget`**.

```
wget "https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.82/blender-2.82a-linux64.tar.xz/"
```

(or whatever is the link to the current version)

Then untar (uncompress) the resulting  file, and move the newly created blender folder to your home directory or a location that is convenient for you. From within the blender folder run the blender executable.

To use blender as a global command from the terminal, add the path of the blender executable to your path environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

after trying many things I install from download the last version
https://builder.blender.org/download/
2.82a and 2.83 works for me
you can also install from snap (snap for ubuntu) (2.82a only)

Comment: I've found that the snap package doesn't recognise my nVidia card, but the same version downloaded directly from blender.org does.